# Algoritmo para percorrer um vetor

Tags: c, c++, lógica

Então, estou com um problema de lógica simples porem não encontro uma boa solução.

**Problema:** Estou querendo percorrer um arquivo de registro (um .csv cujo o qual tenho que resolver um calculo de RMS - Root Mean Square). 
Porem quero que o meu o ultimo valor do loop seja o primeiro da próxima iteração.

Exemplo simplificado:

```
int array[3];
Primeira iteração:
array [0] = 1;
array [1] = 2;
array [2] = 3;
Segunda iteração:
array [0] = 3;
array [1] = 4;
array [2] = 5;
Terceira iteração:
array [0] = 5;
array [1] = 6;
array [2] = 7;
```

Exemplifiquei acima de forma simples para o melhor entendimento do problema.

A situação real é a seguinte:

Basicamente preciso realizar um calculo de RMS, minha janela é de 480 amostras, porem preciso sobrepor 160 amostras a cada iteração (ou seja pegar os últimos 160 valores e torna-los os primeiros da próxima iteração), então achei que a melhor forma é separar a janela em 3 amostras de tamanho 160 ( totalizando 480 amostras), e atribuir essas amostras a índices de um vetor de controle:

```
int controle[3];
Primeira iteração:
controle[0] = dados{0~159};
controle[1] = dados{160~319};
controle[2] = dados{320~479}; // Valor a ser utilizado na sobreposição.
Segunda iteração:
controle[0] = dados{320~479}; // isto é a sobreposição que citei.
controle[1] = dados{480~639};
controle[2] = dados{640~799};// Valor a ser utilizado na sobreposição.
Terceira iteração:
controle[0] = dados{640~799}; // isto é a sobreposição que citei.
controle[1] = dados{800~959};
controle[2] = dados{960~1120};
```

Estou trabalhando com faixas de áudio na frequência de 16Khz preciso de janelas de 30ms (480 amostras) com sobreposição de 10ms(160 amostras) para realizar o calculo de RMS.

Segue a tentativa de codificar este problema, removi as partes de manipulação de arquivo para deixar mais evidente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int j = 0, a = 0, i = 0; // variaveis de iteração.
    int inicio = 0; // Inicio do contador de 160
    int fim = 160; // Fim do contador de 160
    int inicio_principal = 0; // contador do vetor de controle.
    int fim_principal = 3; // 

    // Loop externo para limitar a execução no debug.
    while (a < 1) {
        // Loop para fazer a contagem de 0 a 2 do vetor de controle.
        for(i = inicio_principal; i < fim_principal; i++){

            printf("Loops Externos I = %d\n\n",i); // Debug visual

            // Loop para carregar o vetor com os dados do csv
            for(j = inicio; j < fim; j++){
                printf("J = %d\n",j); //Debug visual.
                // Aqui preenche o vetor com os 30ms de dados.
            }

            // Faz os incrementos de 160 em 160;
            inicio = fim; 
            fim = fim + 160;
        }
        a++; // contador para parar o while.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alguma sugestão para melhor resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percorra as amostras em passos de "janela - sobreposição":

```
#include <math.h>

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < total_amostras; i += janela - sobreposicao) {
  int meanSquare = 0;

  // Percorre a janela (com a sobreposição) calculando a média dos
  // quadrados
  for (int j = 0; j < janela; j++) {
    int amostra = amostras[i + j];
    meanSquare += amostra * amostra / janela; // mean square das amostras da janela
  }

  int rms = sqrt(meanSquare);

  // Use seu RMS da janela como quiser aqui
}

// ...
```

Você vai precisar definir alguns valores também:

- `total_amostras`: Número total de amostras
- `janela`: Tamanho da janela (no seu caso, 480)
- `sobreposicao`: Sobreposição (no seu caso, 160)

Vale notar que seu total de amostras tem que ser múltiplo de 320.

Comment: Tem alguma sugestão de como eu salvaria esse evento? Supondo que eu queira 5ms antes e depois do evento. ( Evento é quando o valor do meu RMS é maior que 1000 por exemplo).